# CSS+HTML: How to draw table/cell border

Tags: html, css, html-table, cross-browser

Here is my CSS code for table:

```
table.t_data
{
    /* border: 1px; - **EDITED** - doesn't seem like influences here */
    background-color: #080;
    border-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
table.t_data thead th, table.t_data thead td
{
    background-color: #9f9;
    /* border: #080 0px solid; - **EDITED** - doesn't seem like influences here */
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 1px;
}
table.t_data tbody th, table.t_data tbody td
{
    background-color: #fff;
    /* border: #080 0px solid; - **EDITED** - doesn't seem like influences here */
    padding: 2px;
}
```

I need to display the following HTML:

```
<table class="t_data">
    <thead style="padding:1px">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Team</th>
            <th>Stadium Name</th>
            <th>Size</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Team 1</td>
            <td>Name 1</td>
            <td>Size 1-1, 2-1, 3-1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Team 1</td>
            <td>Name 1</td>
            <td>Size 1-1, 2-1, 3-1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Team 1</td>
            <td>Name 1</td>
            <td>Size 1-1, 2-1, 3-1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It display perfect (as expected) table in Mozilla Firefox and in IE8:

[image: Mozilla table formatted]

But there are issues in other browsers/modes:

In Chrome the line between head and body is double width:

[image: Chrome table formatted]

In IE8 (switched into IE7 compatibility mode) all lines are double width:

[image: IE table formatted]

Question: what are CSS options to make each line boldness same (1px)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 table.t_data { border-collapse:collapse }
```

Comment: That removed all border at all (no borders, no problem?)

Comment: @Budda That's because you explicitly set all your border to `0px` in your CSS. Set them to `1px` if you want that.